# How to have different color for line and text in StrikethroughSpan?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to change the color of a line in StrikethroughSpan without changing text color?

[image]

```
 setSpan(
        StrikethroughSpan(),
        start,
        start + credit.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
```